# GitHub pencil (Edit) button disappears

Tags: github, edit

I have a GitHub repository where I put my jupyter notebooks in it. While I open my notebooks in GitHub, I usually see a pencil button where I can Edit my notebook:

[image]

However for some other notebooks in the same repository it disappears:

[image]

Why this happens and how to fix it?

Comment: Only files that can be opened by a text editor can be edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simply because of the size of the file. Github does not allow editing large files (not sure what is the exact size limit) It sometimes even restricts viewing such files, and they can be viewed only in the raw mode.

To edit these files, edit them in your local clone and push them to the desired branch using git cli, Github Desktop, SourceTree etc.

***Edit: Answer is outdated now. Please see the workaround mentioned in comments.***

Comment: When the pencil disappeared for me, I was still able to go to `https://github.com/me/my-repo/edit/master/my-file.md` to edit the file.

Comment: Turns out, it was my adblock rules. I had blocked `github.com##.js-sticky` and `github.com##.box-shadow.gh-header-shadow` at some point.

Comment: Related: If you just happen to surf in and see the pencil missing, make sure you are logged in!

Answer (score 1):

As per Wayne Bloss' comment, it's actually possible to exchange the `blob` to `edit` in the URL and edit files that have the edit button hidden.

`https://github.com/orga/repo/blob/branch/folder/filename.extension` becomes `https://github.com/orga/repo/edit/branch/folder/filename.extension`

In my case, it was a lifesaver because I couldn't checkout the file on Windows due to an illegal character in the name of the file.

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling adblockers. Adblockers may block Adobe Experience Cloud.
Especially Ghostery.